# How to install libc6-dev from source with missing header files?

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, glibc, sox

I am currently working on uni project. I am using computer which is available on campus, so I have access to SLURM cluster and so on and so on... The point is I cannot use "sudo", apt-get, yum and all this kind of things. My goal is to install sox from scratch because I need it in one of my projects. I find out that glibc are needed to get this done, so I decided to install it also from scratch. I've followed this tutorial: http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/LDP/lfs/5.0/html/chapter05/glibc.html. It resulted with glibc installed with given folder but not everything is perfect, when I installed sox following this tutorial:
http://akshayc.com/blog/build-sox-from-scratch/ (I set LDFLAGS and CFLAGS according to the place where I installed glibc)

On running command (as I wanted to build using make):
./configure LDFLAGS=-L<path_to_the_installed_glibc>/glibc/lib CFLAGS=-I<path_to_the_installed_glibc>/glibc/include --prefix=<some_path>/sox

I got this error:

```
/<path_to_the_installed_glibc>/glibc/include/gnu/stubs.h:10:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
   10 | # include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:3835: $? = 1
configure:3842: ./conftest
./configure: line 3844: ./conftest: No such file or directory
```

As I understand it correctly, stubs-64.h should be there and I don't know why it is not installed.

I have tried to add modules which are available on cluster and also I've tried to use command:

```
make headers_install
```

as I heard it can be helpful, but I am not really good at Linux.

glibc was downloaded from this site: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Thanks in advance, if anything should be explained more - please, let me know.

Comment: In your place, I would download the debian libc6-dev, I would extract it (`dpkg -x`) and then I would use that with some gcc flags (`gcc -I/hom/matbar99/glibc/usr/include`). I would not use the upstream glibc source, it is a big crap unfortunately and it is usable only for the distro builders. But you can use the "binary" package from any distro, that works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I you it even though I'm working on RockyLinux?

Comment: I do not know RockyLinux, but binary debian packages can be extracted on any distro with an "ar x something.deb". :-)

Comment: I tried to do it your way, unfortunetely I couldn't use dpkg module - it is not allowed on my cluster and I think it can't be installed from source on RockyLinux.

Comment: Because a deb package is an "ar" archive and you can extract it with the command "ar x something.deb". Inside that, there is a data.tar.gz, that contains the package files. These all do not need any debian-specific.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did not read your earlier comment carefully. I did unpacked this but I'm still working on proper including it in gcc flag. Thanks!

Comment: After extracting data.tar.gz into a directory named, for example, "mylibc", you will need to have all the includes in /home/matbar99/mylibc/usr/include. So give a `-I/home/matbar99/mylibc/usr/include` to your gcc and problem solved (probably).

Comment: Do you think I can skip process of installing gcc on my own? It was my first idea, but it went wrong. Now I try to build glibc on my own and add missing headers from your solution. Thank you for your answers, I'm really grateful :)

Comment: Not gcc, glibc. It installs a glibc, more clearly you extract a glibc into your local home, and then you use its headers by the gcc.